# Should we create a tag for the Dungeon Crawl Classics RPG system?

Tags: feature-request, tags

The title **Dungeon Crawl Classics** is applied to various D&D modules (for multiple editions) released by Goodman Games over the years. With their recent release of their Dungeon Crawl Classic RPG, should new tags be created for questions related to their rule set?

At the moment RPG.SE has the tag **[dungeon-crawl-classics]**. This could be ambiguous when users search for questions related to either the modules or the RPG. Perhaps the tags **[dungeon-crawl-classics-rpg]** and/or **[dcc-rpg]** should be created?

My other thought is that questions regarding the modules may not make sense in the first place, in which case the current tag is perhaps sufficient. I'm curious what the community thinks about this.

Comment: [tag:dungeon-crawl-classics-rpg] would be the proper tag for the canonical name as it appears on the book—however, it's 1 character too long for the site's 25-character tag limit. (A fact I learned when I tried to correct that question's tag when it was first posted.) I'd support a [tag:dcc-rpg] tag to solve a *practical* ambiguity problem, but as Pat points out, we don't have one yet. :)

Comment: Given that our tag length limit is now 35, I've renamed [dungeon-crawl-classics] to [dungeon-crawl-classics-rpg], just to have it be canonical. (Synonym made too, of course.)

Answer (score 5):

The bottom line is that there is one question for the game (mine), so worrying about what to tag it isn't very useful as that tag is going to get automatically removed in a couple months.

[dungeon-crawl-classics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeon-crawl-classics) is fine.  Whatever you want to call it, it needs more questions.  My DCC campaign starts next week, perhaps that will help :)

Comment: Beyond that, we don't usually tag module publisher or series, so we're unlikely to run into ambiguity there.

Comment: @AceCalhoon I can see having questions about the whole series that would justify such a tag (e.g., "What are all the cross-connections between the DCC modules?", which is a feature they're known for but isn't well documented, as far as I know), but still I agree that we're unlikely to actually face such problems.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Naturally, anything I say is subject to change without notice :)

Answer (score 3):

We don't "create tags for things."  The tag system is emergent - in fact, tags that aren't applied to m ore than one question are automatically deleted.  If there are more than a couple questions that end up getting tagged about the DCC RPG, then the tag will live.

In terms of what the tag should be for the RPG vs the adventures, dcc-rpg is fine, though everything here is RPGs, so dungeon-crawl-classics would be fine too.  I wish there were more questions about actual adventures, people seem to just be using the site for "core rules" questions and I'm not sure why, but I think preplanning for a possible conflict is putting too much thought into a deliberately folksonomic system.