# The tag length limit is now 35 characters - let us know if there are tags we should now rename

Tags: discussion, tags

> ## Thanks for your help everybody!
>
> Since we seem to have covered all the major cases I'm locking this for posterity. **If there are any other tags that should be renamed [please request it in a new question.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=support+tags)**

---

Just a few minutes ago [we recieved an announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#299490) that the maximum tag character length has been increased from 25 characters to 35 characters. Hooray!

I figure it's a good idea to see if there's any tags in our system that should be renamed to take advantage of that new limit, that we had previously squashed down to fit in the original 25 character limit. **Please respond with your suggestions here of tags we should rename!** Once it's clear that rename is a good idea & the community seems happy with the rename, us diamond moderators can use our ⚡ ***[phenomenal cosmic powers!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SfTfXLLJlzM)*** ⚡ to rename the tag swiftly with minimal disruption to the front page. We'll leave a tag synonym pointing from the old tag to the new one unless there's some reason we ought to not do so (thanks Baskakov for suggesting that).

Let's stick to **one tag that should be renamed per answer**, and please suggest what we should rename it to — we might revise that and go with something different, but your suggestion will help us understand the nature of the rename that ought to happen.

IIRC there's some World of Darkness tags that we shrunk to fit, and [a doctor who tag we could potentially rename](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/requesting-ideas-for-adventures-in-time-and-space-tag) if it would be a good idea.

Some clarifications:

- We can undo the tag rename if it turns out to have been a bad idea, or re-rename it. The best thing we can do is make sure to avoid making such a mistake in the first place though, so please do vote and/or comment to show your support or bring forward concerns with a given rename.
- This won't revoke any badges or tag badge progress. Those of you who have earned a [taxonomist badger](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) keep your badger no matter what happens to the tag that earned you it. (The rename might interrupt earning a new taxonomist badger for that tag, though.)
- Renames unrelated to tag length constraints should be proposed in their own question, not here, please. :)
- The 35 character limit isn't adjustable by us, and probably won't be increased further for a long time due to some architectural concerns in the software that powers stack exchange.

Comment: I propose to make tag synonyms for every rename, the synonym being the previous name.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy That's a good idea. At the very least it would help regulars wondering where a tag went.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy And that's very easy to do with the mod-side renaming tool!

Comment: +1 just for "phenomenal cosmic powers" :D

Comment: We still can't change the overall [tag:fate] tag to [tag:Fantasy-Adventures-in-Tabletop-Entertainment], despite that having been the official title for most of the publication history so far.  It's not a big deal, though; it was always kinda a cop-out acronym, to the point that they scrapped it for the newest editions.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Since you're right that Fate is just a single word nowadays it's fine & accurate leaving it as [fate]. :) It's up to date that way! BESW summarised it well for me one time: it was an age where it was fashionable for RPGs to name themselves as cutesy acronyms, so they probably just came up with one to justify using that name.

Answer (score 10):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): [doctor-who-aitas](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who-aitas) → <del>[dr-who-adventures-in-time-and-space](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dr-who-adventures-in-time-and-space)</del>

(This one has been re-renamed to [doctor-who-roleplaying-game](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who-roleplaying-game), since I learned [they changed the name of the game](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/requesting-ideas-for-adventures-in-time-and-space-tag/7402?noredirect=1#comment23346_7402) -- [see Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who_Roleplaying_Game))

---

the Doctor Who one should definitely be renamed.  Lets go for BESW's original inclination, but add the 'dr who' part so it shows up with other stuff it seems like it should show up with.  I'd add 'doctor who' but that puts us at ***39*** characters, which is four too many.  I thus recommend [doctor-who-aitas](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who-aitas) becomes [dr-who-adventures-in-time-and-space](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dr-who-adventures-in-time-and-space), until some point in the far future when we can have [doctor-who-adventures-in-time-and-space](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who-adventures-in-time-and-space) and feel very silly about the length of our tag names.

The suggestion, btw, is exactly 35 characters.

Comment: We can make a tag synonym so people who start typing "doctor" will still see this tag.

Comment: @doppelgreener sounds like a good plan

Comment: The Doctor Who fans might riot at the fact that the main tag is Dr. Who. Perhaps [doctor-who-adventures-time-space]?

Comment: @Thunderforge I think it's more important that the less-known part of the title is clear.  Everyone will understand that dr-who translates to doctor who, even if they chafe a bit, but I'm not sure visitors will be able to fill in the blanks for adventures in time and space quite as easily. Plus [it's not that big a deal](https://www.reddit.com/r/doctorwho/comments/5xpsqf/dr_who_vs_doctor_who/).  Also it's only thirty two characters and it makes me happy that this is *exactly* the new cap :(

Comment: @Thunderforge And actually there's an expert panel on that and they seem to disagree, overall XD http://screenertv.com/news-features/doctor-who-or-dr-who-experts-weigh-in-debate/

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

- [edge-of-the-empire](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edge-of-the-empire) → [star-wars-edge-of-the-empire](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-edge-of-the-empire)
- [age-of-rebellion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-rebellion) → [star-wars-age-of-rebellion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-age-of-rebellion)
- [force-and-destiny](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force-and-destiny) → [star-wars-force-and-destiny](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-force-and-destiny)

All with synonyms. Any of these may need their synonym broken later if/when we get something else called "age of rebellion" or whatnot, but we can cross that bridge when we come to it.

---

I submit that for clarity, the new Star Wars games should include that prefix: [star-wars-edge-of-the-empire](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-edge-of-the-empire), [star-wars-age-of-rebellion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-age-of-rebellion), and [star-wars-force-and-destiny](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-force-and-destiny). (Age of Rebellion in particular could refer to just about anything to the casual observer who was unfamiliar with the product line.)

If this is rejected for some reason, they should at least have synonyms such that they show up when you start typing "star wars"! Currently only AoR and previous games do.

Comment: Tangentially, the lack of a name for the system still bothers me. I was talking to Jay Little at a con the other day, and I'm going to try to follow up with him to see if he knows of a unified title that would make sense.

Comment: XDDDDD I actually thought Age of Rebellion was a supplement for the old Age of Sail tabletop line!

Comment: These also correspond to the official titles (*Star Wars: Edge of the Empire*, *Star Wars: Age of Rebellion*, and *Star Wars: Force and Destiny*) so it's certainly what we'd have used to begin with if we didn't have to negotiate with a tag length limit at the time. Good suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Pokemon Tabletop Adventures was the only one not given a synonym.

The others are alphabet soup that look much more understandable renamed. Please [let us know](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=support+tags) if any of these renames were counterproductive, such as if people search for the acronym and never the full name.

---

A couple of less common RPGs would benefit from a name change:

- [merp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merp) -> [middle-earth-role-playing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth-role-playing) (keep old as synonym, note that there is a space between "role" and "playing")
- [lotfp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lotfp) -> [lamentations-of-the-flame-princess](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lamentations-of-the-flame-princess)
- [pokemon-tabletop-adv](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-tabletop-adv) -> [pokemon-tabletop-adventures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-tabletop-adventures)
- [rmfrp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rmfrp) -> [rolemaster-fantasy-roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rolemaster-fantasy-roleplaying)
- [rmss](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rmss) -> [rolemaster-standard-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rolemaster-standard-system) (keep old as synonym)
- [tsoy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tsoy) -> [the-shadow-of-yesterday](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-shadow-of-yesterday) (keep old as synonym)
- [tftfv](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tftfv) -> [tales-from-the-floating-vagabond](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tales-from-the-floating-vagabond)

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) both with synonyms

---

Seems like a good candidate:

[m-and-m-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m-and-m-2e) -> [mutants-and-masterminds-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutants-and-masterminds-2e)

[m-and-m-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m-and-m-3e) -> [mutants-and-masterminds-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutants-and-masterminds-3e)

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) though with the short form (wfrp) kept as the primary tag as it's well known and potentially the primary search target. This is similar to how we have dnd-Xe rather than dungeons-and-dragons-Xe.

---

The [Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warhammer_Fantasy_Roleplay) series of tags, possibly with the old tags kept as synonyms:

- [wfrp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp) -> [warhammer-fantasy-roleplay](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-fantasy-roleplay)
- [wfrp-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp-1e) -> [warhammer-fantasy-roleplay-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-fantasy-roleplay-1e)
- [wfrp-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp-2e) -> [warhammer-fantasy-roleplay-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-fantasy-roleplay-2e)
- [wfrp-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp-3e) -> [warhammer-fantasy-roleplay-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-fantasy-roleplay-3e)

Comment: these definitely need synonyms, as "WFRP" is the most common way to refer to them online (afaik)

Comment: @AlexP Out of curiosity, how are we measuring "most common"? When I've played this with friends, we've always called it "Warhammer Fantasy". While I can't say for sure that we were or weren't saying it the most common way, I don't think "WFRP" is universal in quite the same way that "GURPS" is.

Comment: @Thunderfroge how people talk about it on forums like RPGnet.

Comment: @AlexP It could very well be that "WFRP" is more common in written form, while "Warhammer Fantasy"is more common verbally. (GURPS and L5R I think are more common for both forms). I suppose going with the more common text form makes sense, given that we have [dnd] on this site.

Comment: actually pronouncing WFRP is certainly a mouthful :D

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (sort of)

After consultation with a couple of L5R players I've opted to add the longer forms as synonyms pointing to the shorter form. We may do the same with WFRP.

---

The [Legend of the Five Rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_the_Five_Rings) series of tags, with synonyms for the old tags given that "l5r" is a common abbreviation. While the first one is under 25 characters, the rest are over.

- [l5r](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l5r) -> [legend-of-the-five-rings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-the-five-rings)
- [l5r-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l5r-1e) -> [legend-of-the-five-rings-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-the-five-rings-1e)
- [l5r-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l5r-2e) -> [legend-of-the-five-rings-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-the-five-rings-2e)
- [l5r-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l5r-4e) -> [legend-of-the-five-rings-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-the-five-rings-4e)

Comment: Note that there's also now a corresponding tag for the 5th edition in the same vein: [l5r-5e] (click here: [tag:l5r-5e]). It was missing [legend-of-the-five-rings-5e] as a synonym, which I've added now.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

Rename [do-potft](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/do-potft) to [do-pilgrims-of-the-flying-temple](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/do-pilgrims-of-the-flying-temple) (32 characters)

Answer (score 3):

- [cr-calculation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cr-calculation) -> [challenge-rating-calculation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenge-rating-calculation)

Comment: osr should probably be the main tag, there; that's the way I see it used most of the time, even when length isn't a major consideration.  It'd be a good syn to have, though. nwod expansion seems good, but cr is called 'cr' in the first party publised material as well, and much more often than it's called challenge rating.  Another case where a syn would be more appropriate, I think.

Comment: I think we should stick to the "one tag per answer" the question requested. The expansion of the R in OSR is (deliberately) ambiguous in the OSR community since it's different depending on who you ask, and probably should *not* be renamed but instead have new long synonyms map to it. That makes voting on this multiple-tag post hard.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I would have nearly twenty answers if I split all my tag requests up. Is that what you want me to do?

Comment: That's what the question asked for. It would much easier for both debate on proposed renames and mod-side task-tracking. Grouping them by obvious parallels is probably fine though — like, all the Warhammer ones make sense as a single proposal.

Comment: In this case we may want to synonymize the old tag to the new one.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

Rename [larp-mes-camarilla](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/larp-mes-camarilla) to [the-camarilla-minds-eye-society](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-camarilla-minds-eye-society).

The organisation is known as both Mind's Eye Society and "The Camarilla". The second is its original name, then it lost the rights to that name, and now the organisation's in negotiations to get rights to that name back -- and everyone still calls it "The Camarilla".

It's helpful to expand "mes" to "minds-eye-society" for SEO & recognition.

We don't need "larp" in the name and IMO this flows pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

Rename [harp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harp) to [high-adventure-role-playing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-adventure-role-playing). It's not for questions about harps.

Comment: It isn't? Shocking!

Comment: @Conduit It isn't! I'm as shocked as you.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)/[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) (both/either?) this was [renamed instead](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7416/1204) to [the-camarilla-minds-eye-society](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-camarilla-minds-eye-society) due to the relative support between the two options.

---

We could change [larp-mes-camarilla](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/larp-mes-camarilla) to [larp-minds-eye-society-camarilla](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/larp-minds-eye-society-camarilla), but given that the tag has both the current name and the former name in it, we might change it to something else.

Comment: [tag:larp-camarilla-minds-eye-society]

Comment: @Jadasc Is there a preference for whether Camarilla is first or second?

Comment: Crossposted. I think that Camarilla should probably come first, but that's debatable.

Comment: Yeah, for better or worse, "The Camarilla" is what most people still call the organization. It's in negotiations with the new White Wolf to return to that name.

Comment: What about [the-camarilla-minds-eye-society]? (We don't really need "larp" in the tag name right?)

Comment: ^ I've suggested that particular rename [in a separate answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7416/1204).

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) -- renamed to [virtues-and-vices](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtues-and-vices) since "nwod" isn't a thing anymore (*new world of darkness* was officially renamed to *chronicles of darkness*) and the prefix isn't necessary anyway. It's not a tag length thing but we might as well do this. If the name should be further modified (e.g. if [virtue-and-vice] resonates better) please feel free to open a question requesting that.

---

We may consider expanding [nwod-virtue-vice](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod-virtue-vice), which is referring to the mechanic in the New World of Darkness RPG.

Comment: We could just rename it to [virtue-dice]. We don't quality [aspects] as [fate-aspects] or [feats] as [dnd-feats], etc.

Comment: @doppelgreener That's "vice," not "dice," to be clear. Virtues and vices.

Comment: @Jadasc Oops, thanks for that. ([virtues-and-vices]?)

Comment: @doppelgreener I think [tag:virtue-and-vice] would probably be okay, since it's like nature and demeanor.

Comment: atop that: there is no nWoD anymore: it's CoD now.

Comment: @Trish What does CoD stand for?

Comment: Chronicles of Darkness - they rebranded the "new World of Darkness" into "Chronicles of Darkness" for some reasons.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): [dungeon-crawl-classics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeon-crawl-classics) → [dungeon-crawl-classics-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeon-crawl-classics-rpg), which matches the canonical name of the RPG (as opposed to the umbrella brand for the modules + RPG), but [was 1 character too long originally](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1523/should-we-create-a-tag-for-the-dungeon-crawl-classics-rpg-system#comment3529_1523).

Synonyms: [dungeon-crawl-classics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeon-crawl-classics), [dcc-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dcc-rpg)