# Should we rename/synonymise [larp-mes-camarilla] -> [minds-eye-society]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, world-of-darkness

We have a [larp-mes-camarilla](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/larp-mes-camarilla) tag for a LARP organisation devoted to Mind's Eye Theatre ([minds-eye-theatre](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minds-eye-theatre)), a World of Darkness LARP game & ruleset. However, the tag's own wiki suggests this name might not be the best name for the tag:

> The Mind's Eye Society (formerly known as the Camarilla) is an international club for the LARPing of World of Darkness games.

Should we rename this tag to [minds-eye-society](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minds-eye-society)? It seems like something we should do:

- it names the tag after the thing the tag's for, which is *Mind's Eye Society*
- naming it appropriately means we're more likely to show up in search engines for that thing.

I'm not a World of Darkness / Mind's Eye Society player, so I'd like to check this past those who know more before doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this suggestion here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7416/1204) I've renamed the tag to [the-camarilla-minds-eye-society](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-camarilla-minds-eye-society), with [larp-mes-camarilla](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/larp-mes-camarilla) and [minds-eye-society](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minds-eye-society) as synonyms. This way both names it's well known by get covered. We can revisit this together when we know the outcome of the name re-acquisition effort. Best of luck to them.

As usual if we should change the tag name or for some reason I shouldn't have done this, please let us know, and tell us if there's anything specific we should do instead, [by asking a new question about the tag](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=discussion+tags+world-of-darkness).

Answer (score 5):

The MES in the tag is meant to represent "Mind's Eye Society," but the most common name for that organization is still "The Camarilla." In fact, at the national meeting a few weeks ago, the Board of Directors said they were in negotiations with the new White Wolf to regain access to that name. I'd hold off for now.

Comment: Thanks for that. I agree we should hold off. Best of luck to them getting the name back. :)