# Should the [wfrp-4] tag be renamed to [wfrp-4e]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, game-systems, rename-request

Pretty straightforward stuff. We generally use the `-[#]e` tag suffix to denote different editions (presumably because that's how those editions of those games are commonly abbreviated) - and the tags for the previous three editions of *Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay* follow this trend: [wfrp-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp-1e), [wfrp-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp-2e), and [wfrp-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp-3e). (There's also a general [wfrp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp) tag, but that's not relevant here.)

The [wfrp-4](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp-4) tag was created a little over a month ago; I'm guessing the person who created it wasn't aware of the convention for edition tags.

**Should the [wfrp-4](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp-4) tag be renamed to [wfrp-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wfrp-4e)?**

Comment: [related 2017 meta that standardized the original WFRP tags](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7394/4398)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this specific case, yes.

We don't really care about a RPG.SE convention for edition tags.  We care about what players of that game use and find natural and would be searching on and so on.  So if WFRP players tended to refer to it as "WFRP 4" that would be the appropriate tag.

However, on a [cursory Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=wfrp%204,wfrp%204e) and other google check, WFRP 4e is a much more common terminology in that community of play.  So yes, we should change this tag so that it's more aligned with what those folks say and search on organically.

Therefore I've added [wfrp-4e] as a primary tag, added [warhammer-fantasy-roleplay-4e] as a synonym per existing work, and switched the 2 extant questions over to use it.

Comment: Perhaps it should even be renamed [warhammer-fantasy-roleplay-4e] (29 chars) now that we have the room.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie For reference, [the previous tagging discussion on WFRP vs Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7394/4398).